# Laravel プロジェクトをさくら VPS デプロイ時にパーミッション拒否で php artisan key:generate できない

Tags: php, laravel

もともと別のレンタルサーバーで稼働していた Laravel のプロジェクトをさくら VPS に移動させる事にしました。
その際、Laravel を稼働させるためにキージェネレートしたのですが以下のようなパーミッション拒否されます。

**エラー内容:**

```
 ErrorException 

  file_get_contents(/var/www/html/simple/.env): Failed to open stream: Permission denied
at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/KeyGenerateCommand.php:96
     92▕     {
     93▕         file_put_contents($this->laravel->environmentFilePath(), preg_replace(
     94▕             $this->keyReplacementPattern(),
     95▕             'APP_KEY='.$key,
  ➜ 96▕             file_get_contents($this->laravel->environmentFilePath())
     97▕         ));
     98▕     }
     99▕ 
    100▕     /**

      +16 vendor frames 
  17  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
[m2@tk2-209-14402 simple]$
```

以下 `chmd` コマンドで .env ファイルの権限を apache を有効にしました。
/bootstarap/cache/config.php を config.php.old にして無効化するなども試しましたがダメでした。

```
sudo chmod 722 .env
```

権限も以下の通り権限が付与されています。

```
-rwx-w--w-  1 apache apache     821 Jun  4 03:50  .env
```

何か考えられる原因があればご教授お願いします。私事ですが、VPS のセットアップだけでかなり苦労したのでここで何かをインストールし直すとかはしたくないです。
こんな事もできないのは向いてないのかもしれませんが、ここでやめたくはありません。

**実行環境:**
CentOS 8

Comment: 該当のファイルの上部のディレクトリも読み取り権限はありますか

Comment: ご指摘頂きありがとうございます。上部の権限を確認しましたが、アパッチに権限が付与されていませんでした。なので全てのディレクトリに実行、読み取り、書き込みの権限をあたえ、サーバーを再起動するも上記と同じエラーがはかれてしまいます、、

Comment: ありがとうございました。キーは発行できましたが、パーミションを変更したことにより別の問題が発生しました、、また別のページで質問させて頂きます。感謝します。